# what to do if 2 RAM slots are not working

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard

I bought a Samsung laptop model NP350V5C-A0EUK. It worked exactly for 1 year - I bought a new RAM, after that my hard drive got bad memory sectors and I replaced it, then one of my RAM slots was dead, now there is a problem with the second slot.

By any chance can we get RAM slot repaired?

If the answer is NO I suppose I can use other parts of the laptop like processors, RAM, HD, Key pads, display screen so... on is there any way that I can replace some thing like mother board alone to get back my laptop to life?

Thanks in advance for your suggestion

Comment: Replacing the motherboard is generally possible but might be exceedingly difficult. On ThinkPads, it's easy. I don't know your device – you might want to start by looking for a "Maintenance Manual". Of course, the availability of replacement hardware is also questionable.

Comment: You won't be able to get the slot itself repaired.

Answer (score 0):

You generally can't repair RAM slots.  The first place to start is at Samsung's [support page for your laptop](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP350V5C-A0EUK-techspecs).  Look through the manuals, make sure your RAM is a supported speed, your firmware is up to date, etc.

If it truly is your motherboard that is bad (which is what I suspect) then you will probably need to replace it.  A replacement motherboard is going to run about [£ 259](http://www.buy-motherboard.co.uk/laptop-motherboard-samsung-np350v5c-a0euk-core-i5-3210m-25ghz-6gb-motherboard-mainboard-system-board.html).  You can also find someone selling your same laptop but with a broken screen or something and then harvest the motherboard from it.  But you need to be very careful, making sure the MB is the exact same that you need.  Easier to just buy the motherboard.

The support manual might tell you how to remove the motherboard, or it might not.  Going down this road depends on how handy you are with computer repairs and how much time you want to spend.  Might be easier to try to sell the computer at a discount and put your money into a different brand.

Good luck.

Comment: But it doesn't take long for the cost and trouble of doing this to exceed that of ... a new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace(it's no worthy) dimm slots,  you would need to replace mainboard which isn't easy task nor cheap while it's your laptop in question.  My advice would be to sell functional laptop parts and buy new laptop.